# Why is Ronsel lying in the wagon at the end of Mudbound?

Tags: plot-explanation, mudbound

Why is Ronsel lying in the wagon at the end of *Mudbound*? Did he die? Is he being "smuggled" out of town? Did he really make it back to Europe or was that a dream of his?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[According to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mudbound_(film)#Plot), he survives:

> Pappy, who had previously seen Ronsel riding in the front seat with
>   Jamie, finds the photograph of the white woman and mixed-race child on
>   the front seat of the truck. Ronsel, out searching for the missing
>   photo, is picked up by Pappy and other members of the Ku Klux Klan and
>   brutally beaten. Pappy then fetches Jamie and forces him to witness
>   the "trial" prior to the lynching of Ronsel. Jamie tries to fight off
>   the men, but is beaten and restrained, and **Pappy forces him to choose
>   Ronsel's punishment for the "crime" of miscegenation, documented by
>   his photo: to lose his eyes, tongue or testicles.** If Jamie refuses to
>   choose, Ronsel will be murdered. **Jamie is forced to watch the tongue
>   mutilation, and Ronsel is strung up and left for his family to
>   discover.**
>
> [...]
>
> The film returns to the opening scene, and eventually Hap agrees to
>   help but refuses to allow his sons to assist in lowering Pappy's
>   coffin. **Jamie gives the photo of Ronsel's son to Florence to pass on
>   to Ronsel.**
>
> [...] The Jacksons eventually settle on a farm of their own. **A mute
>   Ronsel makes his way back to Europe where he reunites with his
>   girlfriend and son.**

After watching the relevant scenes, it is clear that Ronsel is still alive: you see his mother care for him, etc.. He is likely hidden on the cart to be "smuggled" out of town, and the rest of the movie is "what has happened next".

[The director talked to *Film School Rejects* about this ending](https://filmschoolrejects.com/virgil-williams-changed-ending-mudbound/), because it is different from the book:

> **Virgil Williams:** The ending, of course, was different in the movie than the book and that was a contribution that I made that and that
>   I’m most proud of.
>
> **Andrew Karpan:** Tell me about your decision to change that. It
>   really changes the tone of the movie.
>
> **Virgil Williams:** What’s just more important in a movie than a novel is to leave people in a state of feeling; for me, a film is
>   really made in the language of emotion. And in that book, Hillary
>   [Jordan], she was upset when I told her I was going to change her
>   ending, just alludes to the possibility of what Ronsel could
>   potentially be and where he could potentially go. And I didn’t think
>   that was a satisfying enough ending.
>
> And part of that is that I’m a minority, and, quite frankly, there are
>   too many fatherless black children in the world. **For Russel to truly
>   occupy the space of a hero, he needed to go get his son. It is the
>   very reason he got his tongue cut out and if he didn’t fulfill that
>   relationship, it would have felt very non-cinematic and, quite
>   frankly, not satisfying at all. And, after all that pure truth in the
>   movie, after all that searing idea of America, you really need to end
>   on a hopeful note.** *Mudbound*, I hope, shows us who we were and, in
>   doing that, it shows us who we are and on that hopeful note will
>   inform who we choose to be.

Comment: I saw that on wikipedia, but if that is true, why was Ronsel lying in the wagon? It wasn't clear if he was alive. I considered that the reunion was a dream of Ronsel's and didn't really happen.

Comment: He wasn't on the way home from the "lynching". He had already been home where his mother took care of him. They were going somewhere as a family, but it's not clear where or why. Ronsel was in no shape to go to Europe. Was Ronsel out for a ride or going to be buried?

Comment: I never said anything about him being "on the way home from the lynching". The family were fleeing the town where *the KKK mutilated Ronsel*. "it's not clear where" The next images show them prospering on a farm. "Ronsel was in no shape to go to Europe." It is abundantly clear that Ronsel recuperates and then reunites with his girlfriend and child, this is obviously years later. This is an obvious time lapse, an epilogue to the events of the movie.